# Rails controllers and "protected" variables involving inheritance

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I would like to declare a variable in my `application_controller.rb` controller that is accessible to all controllers that inherit from it.  if possible I would like the variable only accessible in the child classes, nowhere else, including the views (unless specifically passed into the view).

I am new to Ruby and Rails and am unsure if the "protected" scope exists for variables, I have seen that it does for functions.  I have not been able to find a simple answer and I have been experimenting a little in my app with different ways to declare variables and where they can be accessed. That has provided me with no information about how I can accomplish this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    @admin_name = "AdminUserName"
    @admin_password = "AdminPassword"
end

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    http_basic_authenticate_with :name => @admin_name, :password => @admin_password, :except => [:index, :show]

    # controller functions here
end
```

This does not seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have recognized, something like a protected scope does not exist for variables in ruby. You can use an [instance variable](http://www.thesatya.com/blog/2009/06/rails_instance_variables.html) in Rails to set variables in controllers that are accessible to views. It's an old Rails feature that [you can use instance variables set in the controller in the views](http://www.stephencelis.com/2008/09/06/rails-controllers-views-and-variables.html).

Instance variables get inherited from instance to instance

```
class A
  def make_ivar
    @foo = 'bar'
  end
end

class B < A
  def get_ivar
    @foo
  end
end

b = B.new
b.make_ivar
b.get_ivar #=> @foo
```

But be aware that by passing instance variables to views rails [is breaking encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384649/why-use-instance-variables-to-connect-controllers-with-views) and using it through all partials [may not be good practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127838/why-do-people-suggest-not-to-use-instance-variable-for-views-in-ruby-on-rails). Best of all, [replace instance variables with local variables as soon as they land in the views](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/27-replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable)

**UPDATE**

In your case, use [constants](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html). Constants are under the scope of the class they have been defined in and get inherited, but they are not available to the views unless called with scope

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  ADMIN_NAME = "AdminUserName"
  ADMIN_PW = "AdminPassword"
end

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => ADMIN_NAME, :password => ADMIN_PW, :except => [:index, :show]

  # controller functions here
end
```

I guess you do not want to call them in the view. If you really wanted to do that, you can do it like this:

```
ApplicationController::ADMIN_NAME
```

Comment: You've missed inheritance part `class B < A`.

Comment: So, that does not seem to be working for me.  I will update my question with my actual code in a sec to show exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. I assume the admin user name and the password are staying the same, if not, do authentication via models. [devise might help](http://rubygems.org/gems/devise)